# Chrome Process shelljacket

Tags: chrome, process

noticed today this process running on google chrome task manager referencing http://shelljacket.us

[image: chrome process]

If I closed it will restart automatically in a few seconds.

Can anyone confirm if this is safe? How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Task Manager is showing "`Subestrutura: http://shelljacket.us`. This is Portuguese for "`Subframe: http://shelljacket.us`", and means that [Site isolation](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/site-isolation) is enabled in your Chrome browser. [Google's help page on this feature](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/7623121) suggests that you can toggle Site isolation via `chrome://flags/#enable-site-per-process`

Even when you did not enable site isolation, then site isolation will still be used for websites loaded inside a Chrome extension. In your process list, I see that the item immediately above your unwanted process is an extension. To get rid of the frame, you can try to disable the extension.

Seeing an unknown site in a separate process in itself is not something to worry about. But this site in question seems to only contain a tracker from QuantCast, which I consider suspicious from the privacy perspective.

I looked up the extension in the Chrome Web Store (["Hotspot Shield Elite VPN Proxy"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hotspot-shield-elite-vpn/nlbejmccbhkncgokjcmghpfloaajcffj)) and used my [Extension Source Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin) to read the source code of the extension. I found a code snippet in the extension's background script that confirms that the extension is embedding an frame with a QuantCast URL.

```
        }, {
            key: 'quantcast',
            value: function quantcast() {
                if (!sdk.config.reporting.quantcast) return;
                var iFrame = document.createElement("IFRAME");
                iFrame.setAttribute("src", sdk.config.reporting.quantcast.url + '?rand=' + Date.now());
                iFrame.style.width = 0 + "px";
                iFrame.style.height = 0 + "px";
                iFrame.style.display = "none";
                document.body.appendChild(iFrame);
            }
        }, {
```

If you are using that VPN extension for privacy purposes, I would recommend you to immediately uninstall it, because this is clearly a sign that your privacy is violated.